# basic stock trading strategies

Tags: strategy, trading

What are some trading strategies for stocks (just stocks, no derivatives) using freely available [online data sources](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/data-sources-online)?

Comment: Questions asking for strategy ideas are most definitely off topic: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-help-me-develop-this-strategy-questions-in-scope

Comment: "Those who say don't know. Those who know don't say." --Lao-tzu, Tao Te Ching (via Patrick Burns)

Comment: is it just because he didn't phrase his question with the word 'alpha' in it?   Strategies, alpha generation in gneral, are central to quant work.  How could this question possibly be off topic?

Answer (score 3):

There are two broad categories of trading strategies.

1. Momentum strategies(e.g trend following)
2. Mean reversion strategies.

Elder's book outlines the major ones:
[http://www.amazon.com/Trading-Living-Psychology-Tactics-Management/dp/0471592242](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471592242)

And the depressing truth about most of these strategies is outlined by Aronson:
[http://www.amazon.com/Evidence-Based-Technical-Analysis-Scientific-Statistical/dp/0470008741/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470008741)

Comment: I'm not depressed.  I enjoy working in a non-deterministic space.  :)

Comment: I didn't know about the second book. I will read that!