# S&P's Sovereign Ratings: Clarification on Definitions and Symbols

Tags: historical-data, database, bloomberg, credit-ratings

Similar to [an earlier question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/739/are-public-historical-time-series-available-for-ratings-of-sovereign-debt]), I am now looking at S&P's sovereign ratings. Here, as in the case of Moody's, a few things are unclear to me in terms of the definitions used by Standard & Poor's.

1. Several sovereign ratings (Foreign Currency LT Debt, obtained through `CSDR` in Bloomberg Terminal), contain a suffix `u`. For the case of Belgium, example given, ratings are denoted as `AAu` or `AA+u`. What does the `u` stand for?
2. What does the rating `SD` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SD is selective default

http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/06/28/us-cyprus-downgrade-standardandpoors-idUSBRE95R0YQ20130628

+u is unsolicited rating
http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=unsolicited-rating

Answer (score 2):

Credit rating agencies all disclose their codes (and a general methodology) online.

*"The 'u' identifier and 'unsolicited' designation are assigned to credit ratings initiated by parties other than the issuer or its agents, including those initiated by S&P Global Ratings."*

*"SD: An obligor rated 'SD' (selective default) or 'D' is in default... an 'SD' rating is assigned when S&P Global Ratings believes that the obligor has selectively defaulted on a specific issue or class of obligations but it will continue to meet its payment obligations on other issues or classes of obligations in a timely manner. An obligor's rating is lowered to 'D' or 'SD' if it is conducting a distressed exchange offer."*

Source: https://www.standardandpoors.com/en_AU/web/guest/article/-/view/sourceId/504352