# Where to find historical sovereign credit ratings

Tags: credit-ratings, credit-scoring

For my master thesis i am looking for a historical time series of sovereign credit ratings for all countries from Moodys, Fitch or S&P. I have access to Eikon reuters but i cannot seem to find a histrocial time series for countries only the current ratings.

Comment: On Bloomberg terminal, clicking on a rating (like "Fitch B") in CRPR brings up the history. I'd expect Eikon (fka Reuters) to be as simple. You'd best ask Eikon/Refinitive support.

Comment: [This](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/739/are-public-historical-time-series-available-for-ratings-of-sovereign-debt/58450#58450) might be relevant for you.