# Free API for Credit Rating (Moody's, SP500 or Fitch Rating)

Tags: programming, fundamentals, credit-ratings

Is there any API out there that can get Credit Rating? Not just contries, but also for companies.

I found this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/739/are-public-historical-time-series-available-for-ratings-of-sovereign-debt) on quant stack exchange. But it's not an easy API.

definition: A credit rating is a measurement of a person or business entity’s ability to repay a financial obligation based on income and past repayment histories. ([link](https://www.bankrate.com/glossary/c/credit-rating/#:%7E:text=Credit%20ratings%20and%20credit%20scores,known%20as%20a%20FICO%20score.))

Answer (score 1):

If you want yeild for a given rating then FRED (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DBAA) has great data.

Most of the others are in Bloomberg or other payment data sources...

Answer (score 1):

Moodys own CreditEdge API gives credit ratings for corporates as well as other other credit risk data.
https://developer.moodysanalytics.com/products/creditedge

You have to sign up for an account and the documentation is sparse but it appears to be free, at least for now.

Comment: Just to update that this no longer appears to be free. You can create an account but then no data is available due to a quota being applied.