# Where can I find European and Scandinavian convertible bond prices?

Tags: market-data

I'd like to expand on the [Data Sources Online](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/343) question. I found this site for a German convertible bond, all free and not requiring a sign-up.

- [Börse Stuttgart](https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/marketandprices/bonds/bonds.html)
- [German Google](http://www.google.de)

I am looking for similar information for a Norwegian bond.

Comment: German bonds. The search string I used for www.google.de was Bundesanleihen <Company name> <ISIN>. I believe "Bundesanleihen" means "convertible bond." I added "AG" in the name ("AktienGesellschaft," German equivalent of Inc.) This led me to the company site, which had prospectus in German and English, side by side.

Comment: The German analogue to the SEC is the BaFin, the Federal Financial Supervisory Authority (Bundesanstalt für Finanzdienstleistungsaufsicht). BaFin has an English page at http://www.bafin.de/EN/Home/homepage__node.html?__nnn=true. While there was an analogue to http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html, I did not find company I was looking for (privately held?). The BaFin Company Database lists financial instruments (at least that's what "Zins- u. Devisenswaps sowie equity swaps (B5)" looks like). But it does not link to the actual prospectus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand on the problem scope a little, to include company information and stock quotes as well.

### German company information

- [BaFin has an English page](http://bafin.de/EN/Home/homepage__node.html?__nnn=true)

### Norwegian company information

- [Newsweb](http://www.newsweb.no/newsweb/search.do?siteLanguage=en); choose your company
  name from the Issuer pulldown. 
  Change the From Date/To Date and a
  search will give you headlines into
  the issues.

They are not as detailed as a prospectus, but they had the salient details for convertible bonds that I was looking for.

### Norwegian stock quotes

- [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks); enter the company name
  in the search field. The .OL suffix
  means you're on the Oslo exchange.
- [MarketWatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/); enter the company
  name in the search field. The NO:
  prefix means that you're looking at
  Norway.

### Norwegian bond information

- [Oslo Børs](http://ose-demo.manamind.com/ob_eng/markedsaktivitet/bondSearch?newt__menuCtx=1.2.SEARCH); Enter the ISIN.

The bond I was looking for was not found on the Oslo Børs. Instead, I went to 
[Google Norway](http://www.google.no) and typed in the word "marked" (Market) and the ISIN, which had a NO prefix.

This led me to:

- [Börse Frankfurt](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/EN/index.aspx?pageID=126). I entered the
  ISIN in the Name/ISIN/Symbol Search
  field.

That got me the quote I was looking for. Note that while Börse Frankfurt had the quote, Börse Stuttgart did not. Further, the convertible bond I was looking for was denominated in EUR, not NOK, which is probably why it was quoted on a Stuttgart exchange, but not an Oslo exchange.