# S&P 500 list of stocks since 1960

Tags: trading, investing, index

I am looking for the S&P 500 index list of stocks for each day since January 1, 1960.  Does anyone know where I can find these lists?

Comment: ...related question [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/data-sources-online) about online data sources.

Answer (score 4):

Find a friend with a Bloomberg terminal. If you are student check at your university, they might have access to different sources.