# Way to download current stock information (for free)?

Tags: data, market-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Is there a free way to download the current prices (and possibly other data) for stocks for various companies?

Context: This is for a data source for a group programming project for a class.  We weren't assigned this project or even a list of projects to pick from.  If there isn't a way to do this for free, we'll do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a lot of stock prices and similar data from yahoo.com, either directly from the site or with R (getSymbols from the package quantmod).