# Were can I find Historical Interest Rate Data?

Tags: interest-rates, market-data, historical-data, quantitative

Where can I find American historical Savings Account interest (Bank) rates? If you can, please attach corresponding links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What data sources are available online?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: keyword possible. as someone familiar with stack websites, I viewed those comments first and those sites were close to useless.

Comment: @AspiringQuant - yes, there's nothing to suggest using a proxy or T-Bills.

Comment: FRED has [National Rate on Non-Jumbo Deposits (less than $100,000): Savings](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/SAVNRNJ) (but it's a short series), and [1-Month Certificate of Deposit: Secondary Market Rate](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/CD1M) (which is an obvious proxy). In the accepted answer to the question I linked to, under "Fixed Income" is "FRB: H.15 Selected Interest Rates", which contains the 1-month CD series.

Comment: Your university library is the best place to start. Likely they have a data desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4-week US Treasury bill rates would give you a good proxy for USD cash interest.

You can download them from here: http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/data.htm

"The return on domestically held short-dated government bonds is normally perceived as a good proxy for the risk free rate." - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-free_interest_rate)

Comment: This is for a research project, so are you sure that these are equal numerically to actual savings account interest rates?

Comment: Quite sure. See here too: [Investopedia explains 'Risk-Free Return'](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/risk-freereturn.asp).  You'll probably get another answer though, so wait and see.

Comment: very nice. stack websites prove to be more and more enlightening.