# FTSE AIM Components From 2000, 2001, ... 2013

Tags: data, market-data, index

From where can I get a list of historical component lists for the FTSE AIM Index as well as other indices?

I see that there is a page for data sources [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online), but that page does not contain what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

[http://www.google.co.uk/finance/historical?q=INDEXFTSE:AXX](http://www.google.co.uk/finance/historical?q=INDEXFTSE%3aAXX)

A simple google search for "FTSE 100 AIM historical data" brings up numerous sources.

Comment: Please read and understand the question before answering.