# Commodity prices on Yahoo finance

Tags: yahoo, commodities

I tried looking for some decent way to get stock data for general commodities.
I went looking on Yahoo Finance and found https://nz.finance.yahoo.com/q?p=finance.yahoo.com&s=GCN14.CMX.

But this data doesn't update and has no historical data either as the other stocks on Yahoo Finance.

Does someone know what I'm overlooking or another way to get some commodity data online? Pref with some API like Yahoo Finance offers.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online doesn't answer my question because the links to commodities are dead and unclear.

Comment: I've updated the Liffe links but I'm afraid that's the best we have in terms of free/cheap commodity data. Have you had a look at the [Comex-site](http://www.cmegroup.com/company/comex.html), specifically the Market Data section?