# Where can I download intraday series for DAX and S&P500 Index?

Tags: market-data, tick-data, intraday

Where can I download intraday tick data for DAX and S&P500 index prices?

I found only daily closing prices.

Comment: [Related](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/56) (possibly duplicate)

Comment: did you find an intarday free data in the end ? i am also looking for it - and it is not easy....

Comment: @AssiDahan No its not available, apparently only from paid sources e.g. Bloomberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SPX,  [First Rate Data - SPX intraday](https://firstratedata.com/i/index/SPX) has about 15 years of 1-minute intraday data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the **SPX & DAX** data in **CSV** format (you can open in **Excel**):

> http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EGDAXI&d=11&e=1&f=2014&g=d&a=10&b=26&c=1990&ignore=.csv
>
> http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EGSPC&d=11&e=1&f=2014&g=d&a=0&b=3&c=1950&ignore=.csv

and this is the **Yahoo finance** SPX & DAX page to obtain that data:

> [http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^GDAXI+Historical+Prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EGDAXI%20Historical%20Prices)
>
> [http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^GSPC+Historical+Prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EGSPC%20Historical%20Prices)

Comment: Thanks but this is the daily data, intraday means like on 1-min or hourly frequencies...

Comment: you can generate intraday ticks using GBM (Geometric Brownian Motion) combined with OHLC daily data to limit the up/down of the ticks, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202799/python-code-geometric-brownian-motion-whats-wrong

Comment: I've posted new question about generating ticks that can follow OHLC data, in case you're interested - http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/how-do-i-artificially-generate-intraday-ticks-data-from-a-given-input-open-high

Comment: thx its interesting, but I need the empirical real data...

Answer (score 1):

Here are three links:

- [Bloomberg, S&P](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND)
- [Bloomberg, DAX](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/DAX:IND)
- [Börse Frankfurt, DAX](https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/indices/dax)

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for specific source to download the data as e.g. Excel? The links contain intraday but cannot be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There's a company I have used in the past called Portra. They have both intraday and ticks for the DAX and S&P.

[Here](https://portaracqg.com/historical-intraday-futures-data/)'s the link to the intraday page.