# How do I artificially generate intraday ticks data from a given input (Open,High,Low,Close,Volume) using Brownian Bridge method?

Tags: brownian-motion, tick-data

How do I artificially generate intraday ticks data from a given input (Open,High,Low,Close,Volume) using Brownian Bridge method?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge

P.S: Brownian Bridge can generate ticks only with 2 nodes. (with some modification to existing brownian bridge, I think it can be extended to 4 nodes and follow the number of Volume ticks).

Comment: How do you plan to generate data through the high and low price when you don't know the point in time at which those prices occurred?

Comment: The data (ticks) will be artificially generated, and doesn't need *time factor* since it only need an OHLCV as inputs.

Comment: Can't you just model and randomly estimate the time when the highs and lows occur? After that it should be straight forward.

Comment: @jaamor You could do that, but those times will not be independent I suppose. I think the result wouldnt look too good. I would take the high and low value and use it as a dispersion measure to improve my intraday volatility estimator and then create BB paths from it. They will, in general, not reach the high and low values but the question is: Does it make sense to enforce this?

Comment: Here is an engineer's quick and dirty solution: Do what you just said, but generate several paths. Keep the paths where the highs and lows are closer to the actual ones.

Comment: Why don't you do some analysis of high and low times from actual tick data to calibrate your model?

Comment: I would do as jaamor wrote with a simple poisson process for tick times between your two endpoints. Super easy to calibrate too if you have tick data to estimate your lambda parameter. For Volume though, you need some more assumptions and assume some interaction between price changes and volume.