# Historical list of Primary Dealers in Europe

Tags: data, market-making, banks

I would be interested in a list of all the banks and financial institutions that have been Primary Dealers in the European Union from the 1980s until today. For a current list you can check [this pdf by AFME](http://www.afme.eu/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=9229).If the full list of Primary Dealers isn’t available, then a list of Inter-Dealer banks would suffice.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the ECB https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money/mfi/html/index.en.html? They don't necessary single out dealers but if you get hold of a list of dealers that might help. For a definite answer consider a request to the ECB https://www.ecb.europa.eu/ecb/history/archive/intro/html/requestform.en.html. BTW. data sources are discussed here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141