# Best sources for worldwide balance sheet data?

Tags: data, banks

I’m interested in databases with quarterly balance sheet data of the financial sector.  I’m aware of the following datasets:

-[Compustat](http://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds//ds/compm/nam.cfm?navGroupHeader=Compustat%20Monthly%20Updates&navGroup=North%20America)

-[Compustat Global](http://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds//ds/comp/globalm.cfm?navGroupHeader=Compustat%20Monthly%20Updates&navGroup=Global)

-[Bankscope](https://bankscope.bvdinfo.com)

Can someone point out other sources with, possibly, international quarterly data and time series that go at least back to 2000.

Thank you

Comment: You can find data sources discussion here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141

Comment: @RndmSymbl That question is about online databases. As I understand it anything will do for franic.

Answer (score 1):

Worldscope is pretty standard for international fiscal data.

http://www.rimes.com/thomson-reuters-worldscope

Comment: Bloomberg has been improving over the years and does go back into 90s for most developed nation stocks and early 2000s for Emerging nation stocks.

Capital IQ & Factset Fundamentals also started working off the Compustat / Worldscope dataset but now offer their own datafeeds.