# Historical Data - Free Sources in 2015?

Tags: historical-data

I've found some free sources for stock historical data but none that aren't broken links or give me quite what I need. I want...

For NASDAQ, S&P 500, DJIA:

Historical data for the past 5 years that includes a complete list of all stocks in the index, the year end closing price, and the year end shares outstanding.

Seems like a simple request but I can't get this anywhere.

Comment: All data sources questions were merged in a single question. Feel free to comment or raise flags there is some links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.quandl.com

They have various feeds of historical stock data.

Edit: check out the post for more details.
[What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: Feel free to add your answer there if they don't talk about Quandl already. But please add some comments with it like how much of it is free, have you worked with it already and so on.