# Where can one find realistic historical transaction costs?

Tags: arbitrage

I am interested in strategy simulation at different frequencies (high frequency and daily frequency) and I want to compute the optimal frequency of execution.

To do this, I need to obtain realistic historical transaction costs from 1987 onward.

Does anyone know where one might obtain such a database?

Comment: We usually group all data in [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online), but this specific request is interesting and quite uncommon so I'll leave it open see what the community thinks

Comment: If you're on the buyside, you should call your prime broker. I know a few banks/investment banks (at least used to ) provide clients access to their algo trading data so that they can build these transaction cost models; I don't think you'll be able to find a nonproprietary source for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read papers about market impact. You will find a lot of information about transaction costs. Two recent ones:

- [Market impacts and the life cycle of investors orders](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0217), by Emmanuel Bacry, Adrian Iuga, Matthieu Lasnier, CAL
- [Beyond the square root: Evidence for logarithmic dependence of market impact on size and participation rate](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2152), by Elia Zarinelli, Michele Treccani, J. Doyne Farmer, Fabrizio Lillo

The first one use the database of a broker, and the second one the [Abel Noser database](http://www.ancerno.com/AboutUs/OurData.aspx).

Once you selected the market impact model you want, you can convoluate it with your trading profile to obtain your expected trading costs.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer because it is helpful, but upvoting requires 15 reputation. Sorry! I will leave this open for 7 days and if there is nothing better, I will accept your answer.