# Data exported from Capital IQ, FactSet, Bloomberg, Compustat

Tags: equities, data, historical-data, fundamentals, investing

I'm looking for reliable data on US equity fundamentals, but not sure which vendor provides these features:

1. Unlimited data export
2. Coverage of disbanded entities (bankruptcies, M&A)
3. Financial statements, including values initially stated by the company
4. Historical data prior to 1990

Does any of the vendors have a comprehensive list of variables available for each company through its platform? Or a sample profile exported from its dataset?

I found [one for Compustat](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/demo/demoform_compustat.cfm?) and [Zacks](https://www.quandl.com/data/ZFB), but not for the others. Basic financials (earnings, net margin, price) are freely available, but vendors like Capital IQ have a more comprehensive coverage.

Or maybe some vendor sells all historical data on US public companies as a single dataset?

Comment: So you answer your own question two times ... maybe one time is enough ..

Answer (score 6):

### Morningstar

Morningstar partnered with Quantopian, and the latter published the structure of Morningstar's equity fundamentals database:

- https://www.quantopian.com/help/fundamentals

Quantopian users can use this data for free.

Answer (score 5):

## Compustat

- supports unlimited data export
- keeps the history of disbanded entities
- provides restatements since 1950 + point-in-time data since 1986
- coverage since 1950
- [list of variables](http://finance.fbv.kit.edu/rd_download/NorthAmerica_DataGuide.pdf) (data guide)

Compustat is a S&P subsidiary. It goes as a plugin for CapitalIQ (also S&P), [WRDS](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/), [CRSP](http://crsp.org/files/ccm_data_guide_0.pdf), and other platforms. Pricing starts from \$3k. A platform typically costs another \$10-20k and provides additional data (deals, management, macro). Access via data feed costs \$15k+. The prices depend on your region.

Example of the variables available in Compustat via WRDS:

- https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/demo/demoform_compustat.cfm

Compustat + CRSP:

- http://crsp.org/files/ccm_data_guide_0.pdf