# List of Economic Data for Index Forecast

Tags: market-data, forecasting, econometrics

What econometric symbol list (or tickers) could be used to forecast return of global stock market indexes (S&P500, TSX, CAC40, ...) and their subsectors?

I'm aware of the answer to question: 
[What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

What I'm looking to build is a actual list of tickers that could be used from the databases stated above.

Please add to the follow items:

- US Economy: FRED-MD: A Monthly Database for Macroeconomic Research
  https://research.stlouisfed.org/wp/2015/2015-012.pdf
- Canada:
- Euro Zone:
- Asia-Pacific Zone:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three categories of variables in Fred that have been shown to have *some* predictiveness for [longer run] stock returns:

-Interest rate spreads (constructed from the following)

FEDFUNDS Effective Federal Funds Rate

TB3MS    3-Month Treasury Bil

GS1      1-Year Treasury Rate

GS5      5-Year Treasury Rate

GS10     10-Year Treasury Rate

-Credit spreads

BAAFFM Moody's Baa Corporate Bond Minus FEDFUNDS

-DivYields & E/P ratios

S&P div yield S&P's Composite Common Stock: Dividend Yield

S&P_PE_ratio  S&P's Composite Common Stock: Price-Earnings Ratio

Comment: Would you have a reference for this? Alternatively, do you imply that taking these variables for other economy would also have "some" predictiveness ?

Comment: It is a controversial area. Some references:

Campbell, J. Y., and R. J. Shiller, 1998, “Valuation Ratios and the Long-Run Stock Market Outlook,” Journal of Portfolio Management 24(2), 11—26

Fama, E. F., and K. R. French, 1988, “Dividend Yields and Expected Stock Returns,” Journal of Financial Economics
, 22, 3—25.

Fama, E. F., and K. R. French, 1989, “Business Conditions and Expected Returns on Stocks and Bonds,” Journal of Financial Economics, 25, 23—49