# BLS v2 API took 20+ minutes to publish data where is immediate data available?

Tags: data, programming

First, I should state that I built a Java program that uses HTTP Components to keep in sync with server time for my broker.

Once `7:29:59` comes around the program begins sending requests to the `bureau of labor statistics v2 API` so that when the data for non farm payrolls gets published I can immediately hedge and adjust my portfolio before to significant of a move in the market occurs.

However last Friday it took over twenty minutes of return no value before the data was finally updated and my orders where filled.

I wanted to know if there are any alternative sources I can receive immediate data from?

Comment: did you see http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online?rq=1  ; quandl.com has a good api

Comment: I am using the BLS API (the BLS publishes the non farm payroll)

Comment: @FreepromTech how much are you willing to pay?

Comment: I was expecting it would be free since it's published by a government agency