# Using news to predict Stock Prices dataset

Tags: programming, market-data, machine-learning

In order to build Regression or Deep Learning models for predicting the market, we need a bunch of historical data.

Prices and technical indicators are easily accessible, but getting news from the web or using the frequency of keywords searched at google as input data is much more complex.

Are there any available datasets with information where we can use to train our models? Kaggle had a competition using a similar dataset but now the competition is closed and can not be accessed.

Alternatively, is there a clever way to draw such data?

Thank you!

Comment: might be a duplicate question of getting sentiment data and leads contained there: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/which-proxies-to-user-for-investor-sentiment-and-industry-performance-and-where

Comment: As there are papers on this topic, my suggestion would be to read those and see what sources they used. From memory, Refinitiv (formerly Reuters) is one but it will likely be expensive.