# Where to find historical time series data for number of new investor accounts

Tags: data

I am examining the impact of investor sentiment on the probability of stock market crises. I am constructing a composite measure of investor sentiment according to the methodology used in this paper http://121.192.176.75/repec/upload/201312051625034821.pdf

One of the variables used in the composite index is the "number of new investor accounts" - top of page 6. This paper uses data for the Shanghai composite index and the Shenzhen Index.

I am looking for data on the number of new investor accounts for the S&P 500, FTSE 100, NIKKEI 225, S&P/TSX and the ASX 200.

I have searched Bloomberg and datastream but cannot find anything. Any suggestions on where I might find such data would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I thought an investor account is private.

Comment: Indeed, hence why I have been a bit skeptical about the possibility of obtaining any data on the variable. Unless you have a different interpretation of what they mean by "number of new investor accounts"..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data sources are available online?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: Even after looking at that thread, I still have no idea where to look.

Comment: Did this help you at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you best bet is **calling up/emailing the SEC** and asking to request some records from them.

> First, do a search.

https://www.sec.gov/search/search.htm

> **"Search SEC Documents"** for what you seek and if not, request the records with a FOIL Request.

Request the docs from them using the **" Freedom of Information Act "** if it does not come up, call them and see if they can release the information you seek because they get the information about new accounts from broker-dealers.

[image: Books and Records Requirements for Brokers and Dealers Under the Securities Exchange Act of 1934].  --https://www.sec.gov/rules/final/34-44992.htm

> Below is where you go if what you seek is not coming up where you searched through the document above because it may be **non-public**.
>
> -https://www.sec.gov/oso/foia-freq-docs-custom-list-page**
>   -Phone number FOIA Office phone: **(202) 551-7900**

****You will not be able to get as granular as you like unless you get approval from them meaning they know you will not do anything that is against foil law with it.

========================================================================

Good Luck!