# List of Intraday stock prices API

Tags: programming, trading, data-source

I am looking for an API to request intraday data for the London stock exchange. I have seen products like eSignal but this seems to include a lot more than the simple data as XML or JSON and is fairly expensive. The idea is to request data and analyse in an application that I have written so all I need is a real time source. Is there anything available like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a good question for a Community Wiki ^^

Please note this wiki is devoted to **Intraday** data only.

If you are looking for other financial data : see [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/7008)

**List of Available Intraday API**

*Please add your links with the following syntax:  1) website - 2) minimum time frame - 3) Is it possible to retrieve **Real Time** data ? ( Yes or No )*

---

> Not Free of Charge

- [Quandl API](https://www.quandl.com/blog/quandl-launches-intraday-data-2)   ,  One minute Bars, No
- [TickData API](https://www.tickdata.com/) ,Tick by Tick data ,  No
- [Bloomberg API](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/) ,  Tick by Tick data , Yes
- [Esignal](http://www.esignal.com/), Tick by Tick data , Yes
- [BarChart](http://www.barchartmarketdata.com/fees), Tick by Tick data , Yes

---

> Free of Charge

- [Stooq.com](http://stooq.com/db/h/)  - 5 minutes - No  (*Nb: Not a real API, just a download page*)

Answer (score 1):

Try [TallacOptions](http://tallacoptions.com). They offer US markets data for sure.

Comment: Only `EOD` data is free. So that is not a free API. In addition there lowest time frame is 3 seconds.

Comment: It does not seem to be practical. After creating a apikey, it throws  `"Message": "Token already used!"` or  `"Message": "Restricted resource! Please See EOD data access scheme."`. The only thing that works is create a token.

Answer (score 1):

The best vendors that offer extensive intraday data on other exchanges, so far I know https://www.quandl.com, https://www.onetick.com and https://www.tickdata.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for FTSE index data (and not constituent stocks) the [firstratedata](https://firstratedata.com) has 5-min intraday bars going back to 2012.