# pandas pull 500 stocks through data reader

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, yahoo, yahoofinance

Is it possible to pull 500 stocks from yahoo finance through the pandas data reader at once?

I need to grab large chunks of adj close prices for different tickers. I can pull like 10-20 at a time and append to a pandas dataframe but i'm ideally looking to grab more than that.

Any other sources where I can grab this end of day data?

Comment: Your second question has been answered: [What data sources are available online?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/848)

Answer (score 2):

You can download all the company names and values and a lot of other stuff from the Nasdaq or NYSE via http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx in .csv , then you can process that with df = pd.read_csv(Filename.csv)