# Are there any free data of DAX or DAX future in 1-second or 1-minute time resolution?

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data

Are there any free data of DAX or DAX future in 1-second or 1-minute time resolution ? I would be happy to buy them but everywhere prices starts from 1k $ (minimum value of order), 2016 alone would be enought

I've read this : [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: I recently bought two years of FDAX trades from tickdata.com for 250 USD. Not affiliated to them and can recommend.

Comment: I think wss://ws-feed.gdax.com

Answer (score 4):

If you shop [Eurex](https://datashop.deutsche-boerse.com/tick-data?q=FDAX) for 1-minute bars, it's actually fairly cheap: comes down to 37 euro for month of data for DAX futures.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Tickstory](https://tickstory.com/#features) downloads, among other assets, DAX data from [Duksacopy](https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/). However, I don't know if it's their CFD on index or future. [Zorro](http://www.zorro-trader.com/download.php) also provides 1-minute OHLC data for DAX.

Comment: Can confirm that the Zorro data is 1 min for DAX

Comment: +1. 1min and 3yr timespan at Duksacopy atm. Data is downloadable as CSV if you create a free user. Seem pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

Deutsche Börse  offers free historical data for EUREX and XETRA at 1 min aggregated Levels here https://github.com/Deutsche-Boerse/dbg-pds. I do know that maybe not every instrument is available, but the data is free of charge and an API is available or can be programmed quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can find cheap data on https://firstratedata.com/b/29/futures-most-active
DAX Fut minutes OHLCV are included in the most active bundle data pack, for 200USD 15 years of data.

[image: Bundle pack]

[image: DAX futures available]

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
https://www.backtestmarket.com/en/dax-1m
I haven'tried it yet but the sample seems good to me.