# Alternative to Quandl for Europe or France equities?

Tags: equities, data

Quandl is perfect for US equities, but lacks data for Europe/France.

I'd like to find the equivalent of the following data for Europe/France:

- [Zacks Daily Maintenance](https://www.quandl.com/databases/ZDM)
- [Zacks Company Profiles](https://www.quandl.com/databases/ZCP)
- [Core US Fundamentals Data](https://www.quandl.com/data/SF1-Core-US-Fundamentals-Data)
- [Wiki EOD Stock Prices](https://www.quandl.com/data/WIKI-Wiki-EOD-Stock-Prices)

So basically: company profiles, maintenance data, historical daily prices with dividends and splits updated daily, historical fundamentals updated daily.

What are the alternatives except an expensive morningstar direct membership?

---

Edit:
The other question does not include the data I am looking for. It is only vaguely related.

Here are the sources provided in the other question:

- http://finance.yahoo.com/ : only includes prices. No API for dividends or splits or fundamentals or anything else.
- http://www.iasg.com/managed-futures/market-quotes : not a data provider.
- http://kumo.swcp.com/stocks/ : only for S&P 500.
- http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html : not providing the data I'm looking for.
- http://unicorn.us.com/advdec/ : only US.
- http://siblisresearch.com/ : not providing the data i am looking for.
- http://usfundamentals.com/download : only US.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Possibly related: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Comment: As I understand it you want the data from an online source (so not Bloomberg or [CRSP](http://www.crsp.com/)) then it would be a duplicate. Please clarify if I misunderstand. The fact that that information is not available there is very unfortunate and probably means that no source is known to the community.