# Extract data from Wall Street - Programming

Tags: market-data

I want to extract data from the wall street. I am a programmer in Django/Python, and I need the best source for price date, fundamental data. I wanted to extract it directly from google finance, but it seems that google finance with shut down in october. There was a plugin with google finance, but because of that reason, I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to say that I don't like the way you have phrased your question - it denotes a lack of any research effort. However, here at QFStackExchange there is this useful answer - [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)