# API for fundamentals for NSE and BSE

Tags: equities, programming

I want APIs for accessing fundamental data of all stocks in NSE and BSE India. I have searched a lot But no luck. Any such services available please guide me.
I'm looking for specifically quarterly EPS of last 4-5 years, revenue etc.

Regards

keerthan

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

that said, you're unlikly to find anything free.  The EDGAR database in the US has access to most filings data, but only provides full access for a fee.  I don't deal much with Indian equities, but I can't imagine you'll have an easier time with those than US stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Broker API for that. Interactive Brokers is one of the most famous. This is their general information about their API:

> Build Your Own Trading Application
>   IB API - Build a complete trading application that connects to our advanced order routing and trading system using our IB Application Programming Interface (API):
>   Choose from among several available IB API programming languages, including Java, .NET (C#), C++, ActiveX or DDE.
>   If you're a beginner API programmer, use our DDE for Excel API sample as the basis for your DDE-based trading application.
>   The IB API requires no additional technical overhead.
>   FIX CTCI – For clients with the knowledge of and resources to support FIX CTCI, a robust, industry-standard solution.

Get Market Data and Chart Data:

> IB API – Subscribe to and view market data through your custom application while taking advantage of Trader Workstation, our innovative trading platform.
>   IB Gateway – Connect to IB market data in a seamless experience with a minimal interface.
>   WT Web API –Add market data and chart data to your custom trading interface or website.

Take a look to their website:  [IB API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041).