# Where can I find data on US bank interest rates or 4-week T-bill rates dating back to 1970s or earlier?

Tags: interest-rates, treasuries

Where can I find data showing 4-week T-bill rates or U.S. savings accounts' interest rates from 1960s to present, or 1970s to present?

Comment: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/search?st=treasury+bill+rate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify which kind of treasury bill I seek data for. Updated my question

Comment: The link that Helin posted has 4 week treasury bills, among others

Comment: @AlexC The 4-wk T-bill data in that link does not go back to 1970s or earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each bank is able to set their own rates and terms for savings accounts, this is a difficult question.

4 week Treasury Bills only started trading in July 2001.
Source:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/history/histtime/histtime_bills.htm

You might want to look at the Federal Funds Yield which is the overnight rate that banks charge each other for loans held at the Federal Reserve Bank of New York.

Recent data is available here:
https://www.newyorkfed.org/data-and-statistics

Historical data can be found on the FRED site back to 1954.
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/FEDFUNDS.txt

Comment: How comparable is the Federal Funds Yield rate to interest charges on depositors’ accounts?

Comment: They are going to be correlated, but you need to take into account that a bank has costs associated with providing a service so the rates are going to be typically about 2% lower but this will vary from institution to institution.  For example, I just looked up Citi's savings account interest rate for California, which is 0.04%.  The current Fed Fund yield is 1.91%.