# What preprint repositories are available online?

Tags: finance, data, economics, data-source

Besides [data sources](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/29318), what preprint archives are available for academics and practitioners in the fields of Quantitative Finance and Economics?

I have subscribed Google Scholar alerts and regularly see on [arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/archive/q-fin). Nevertheless, i feel like i also have to regularly check forthcoming papers on each of the high ranking journal websites in finance on their own. Otherwise, i certainly would overlook many important research articles.

Comment: http://www.ssrn.com

Comment: arXiv and SSRN are the best IMO.

Answer (score 1):

you can search for quantitative finance on [SSRN](https://www.ssrn.com/)