# Indian Securities Sector and Industry performance history data

Tags: historical-data, performance

I am looking for data of Indian Industries and Sector's performance historical data for each and every date for over the last 10 years period of time. If it is not available, Could I get every month-end or year-end performance for the last 10 years? Where could I get the Historical Performance data of Industry and Sector of Indian Stock market?

We are managing for 30 different securities under 30 or more different Industry and sectors.

For example, we are managing `Hindustan Copper Limited` which `NSE` listed this Industry as `COPPER & COPPER PRODUCTS`. I am looking for the historical performance data of the `COPPER & COPPER PRODUCTS` for the last 10 years. Likewise, I am looking for other securities also that listed in NSE. 
Where could I find a free data source or paid service?

Comment: What specific data are you looking for? A specific index? A specific sector? Simply all of India? Please restate your question and explain exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Additionally, are you willing to pay for this data?

Comment: @AdB: I edited my question now. Is the details enough?

Comment: @BobJansen: Is my edit ok?

Comment: Regarding free data, check out [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/168/848). Can you give ballpark estimate of your budget?