# How to construct continuous futures contracts with multiple maturities

Tags: futures, modeling, continuous-time

I am trying to replicate the Schwartz-Smith (2000) model and having an issue understanding what the data is and how to generate it. Specifically, the authors use a table of continuous futures with expirations maturity = [1/12,5/12,9/12,13/12,17/12]. How exactly is this created? I have daily prices for a series of gold futures: GCM1, GCZ7, GCZ9, GCM9, GCV8, GCQ7 for example, but these contracts all have a start and end date. What is the way to create the 5-month continuous futures contract from this data?

This was asked in [Where can one find the daily prices of commodity futures of multiple maturities and time to expiration of the contracts?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49397/where-can-one-find-the-daily-prices-of-commodity-futures-of-multiple-maturities) but the answers were about the data sources, not the mechanics of stitching the contracts together. Additionally, I can find resources about the different weighting methods when stitching two contracts together, but nothing about how to assemble the time series.

Comment: I just found this great description [link](https://data.nasdaq.com/databases/SCF#anchor-knowledge-base) but I would really like a simple explanation on how to create the five different maturity continuous futures

Comment: Your link does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure about a general approach to this, or how to answer my specific question about how to create a five month continuous contract from a series of futures. But, in order to replicate the data found in the Schwartz-Smith (2000) or Schwartz (1997) papers, I needed to find a Composite Commodity Future Continuation. In this case, I used the Refinitiv GCc1, GCc5, GCc9, GCc13, and GCc17 data series to create my table of continuous futures with expirations maturity = [1/12,5/12,9/12,13/12,17/12].