# Automatically gathering closing prices for stocks listed on different exchanges

Tags: programming

I am looking at the holdings for a particular ETF. A lot of the tickers represent stocks on different exchanges. For example for one of the holdings the stock appears on Yahoo Finance, but for another holding the stock isn't on Yahoo finance.

I want to automatically get closing data for each of these holdings, how should I go about this? I am using Python, below is what I have so far.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'
panel_data = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: Foreign exchanges are the least of your problems. My understanding is that Yahoo no longer supports pandas_datareader (as of 2 years ago). Your example is almost 3 years old. Does it work for you today? I suggest you find a data source other than Yahoo.

Comment: What else have you tried besides Yahoo? Did you look through the links in this question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online