# Reputable source for historical US-listed EOD options data for backtesting

Tags: options, data-source, option-data

I've gone through the [data thread](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online) and found a few viable options.  ivolatility.com in particular has what I'm looking for (EOD US-listed NBBO options price data, volume, OI, history back to 2000) but would cost about \$3k for the year including their monthly subscription fee.  CBOE would cost about $2800, but only goes back to 2005.  Not as concerned about additional stats (eg, IV, greeks, etc) initially.

Can anyone who's more familiar (either in the industry or in personal pursuits) with backtesting with options provide any guidance in addition to the thread.  I'm not in a position to go with some of the larger big-boy commercial providers, so really just looking for a data dump of historical data that I can use for testing.  Realize options data is expensive but wonder if there may be better options.

Comment: I use sometimes historicaloptiondata.com. The service is nice and the price is quite cheap. But I can't say much about the quality of the data

Comment: @DomingoBrown, interesting.  I hear you can't vouch for quality, but in your experience, any issues or mostly OK?

Comment: Mostly OK, but if you use this data source in production, expect some issues quite often (let's say once in a month I do not get my data and I have to send an email). I never had this issue with ivolatility for example