# Discrepancy in stock volume values for different intervals for the same day on Yahoo Finance

Tags: data, market-data

everyone.
Probably, someone else before me noticed that peculiar behaviour but I have not found any thread with a relevant title.

Anyway, here is the case. I have attached a screenshot which displays  the number of shares that have been bought and sold for 07.02.2020 of Square Enix Holdings. Here is the link->>>[interval 1d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buDjn.jpg)

As it can be observed volume value for the whole day is 1.53M.

However, if interval is changed to 1H instead of 1D the following volume values hours-wise are displayed:

2/7 9 AM: 515.8K
2/7 10 AM: 229.1K
2/7 11 AM: No volume at all
2/7 12 PM: 942.4K
2/7 1 PM: 236.6K
2/7 2 PM: 1.56M

If to sum it up, then the final value is 2.97 M.

It would be great if someone clarifies it to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular trading hours for this stock on its primary exchange (in Tokyo) are from 09:00 JST - 11:30 JST, then it closes for 1 hour, then it reopens and trades from 12:30 JST - 15:00 JST.  On top of that, trading runs continuously from 08:00 JST - 16:00 JST on non-primary exchanges.

1.53M is the volume according to the primary exchange (link below). The hourly data being displayed by Yahoo is a combination of primary and non-primary exchanges.  The 11 a.m. hour is blank because the stock closes temporarily from 11:30 to 12:30 -- this is obviously wrong yet this is how Yahoo reports it nevertheless.

It is probably a better idea for you to look for another data source.  Looking through this post might be a good place to start: [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

You can find data from the primary exchange here: [Japan Exchange Group](https://quote.jpx.co.jp/jpx/template/quote.cgi?F=tmp%2Fe_stock_detail&QCODE=9684&MKTN=T&cht=21&mode=D#chart)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! If it is not hard for you, could you please send to me a link where non-primary exchanges are explained as googling I have not succeed to find a decent explanation

Comment: Or ”non-primary” means secondary? If yes, then no need to provide me with anything.

Comment: @user641597 non-prinary would be exchanges other than the primary listing exchange.  For example, an NYSE listed company can have volume on other exchanges like IEX or Nasdaq

Comment: Hi, thanks again.

Comment: However, how do these shares end up on none-primary exchanges? I know there are few dual-listed companies, such as Yandex, which stocks are traded in Moscow Stock Exchange and on Nasdaq. So is Moscow Exchange considered as none-primary? And how can I find volume data regarding these none-primary exchanges in Square Enix example? Anyway, thanks for your replies!