# Historical SPX Intraday data with volume

Tags: historical-data, index, volume, intraday, spx

I am looking for historical SPX 1minute data containing volume.
Anyone knows where to get them from?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you read through the [master list](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/35)? It might be buried in there somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Interactive Brokers account, you can get historical intraday index data, including SPX, through their [API](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html).

Many developers find using the Interactive Brokers API to be a challenge, especially for collecting large amounts of data. If you want a more turnkey access, you can check out [QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/data/), which provides data collection tools on top of the Interactive Brokers API (among other data providers).

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with QuantRocket.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, algoseek has that kind of data. Their S&P 500 Trades and Quotes+minute bar data set contains OHLC, FINRA volume and etc. You can find a sample of their dataset [here](https://www.algoseek.com/products.html#us_equity_index)