# Downloading Historical Data from Finam.ru

Tags: equities, programming, data, intraday, historical

I am looking for free historical intraday data (e.g., 30 mins, 1 hour) and I have came up to this website finam.ru, which is in Russian but it can be translated.

The link to download the data is [here](https://www.finam.ru/profile/akcii-usa-bats/google-inc/export/?market=25&em=20590&code=GOOG&apply=0&df=17&mf=10&yf=2019&from=17.11.2019&dt=17&mt=10&yt=2019&to=17.11.2019&p=7&f=GOOG_191117_191117&e=.txt&cn=GOOG&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=1&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=1&at).

However, after the download is completed I get a txt file (or csv) with this strange message:

> ¬˚ Á‡ÔÓÒËÎË ‰‡ÌÌ˚Â Á‡ ÒÎË¯ÍÓÏ ·ÓÎ¸¯ÓÈ ‚ÂÏÂÌÌÓÈ ÔÂËÓ‰.

Has anyone used this source before? Do you know how to actually download the data?

Alternatively, do you know any other source I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has a lot of data sources: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify smaller timesteps, otherwise this is just some error in Russian.

Use https://pypi.org/project/finam-export/