# Daily Stock Data Sources and API

Tags: programming, equities

I am looking to get stock data for various stock symbols over a period of time.
I am primarily only concerned with the adjusted close price but of course any additional stock data could be useful.

Would someone recommend some programming APIs or any other method to obtain this information.
From the searching online that I haven't found any good ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online) . If non of the sources meets your criteria, you will need to consider providers like Bloomberg, where you will need to pay for the data. On the other hand, they will have more reliable data, a nice API and allow to to choose what adjustment you want.

Comment: See specifically https://polygon.io/ or https://www.alphavantage.co/ on that list. They fulfil your requirements.