# Data on historical, cross-country REAL yield curves (i.e. inflation-linked bonds)

Tags: fixed-income, historical-data, yield-curve, bloomberg, inflation

I asked [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69659/data-on-historical-cross-country-nominal-yield-curves) about data on a data source for historical yield curves for many countries. Many central banks (linked there, in Helin's answer) publish estimates for their *nominal* yield curves.

But most do not do so for historical ***real*** yield curves, i.e. the yields on inflation-indexed bonds. The [US](https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2008/200805/200805abs.html) and [UK](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/yield-curves) do; I have not found any other country that does so.

Partially this is because not all countries issue inflation-linked bonds; and among those that do, many do not (or have not historically) issued at enough different maturities to fit a yield curve.

**Does any data source have more comprehensive cross-country coverage for *REAL* yield curves?**

Thank you!