# free download of 1- or 5-minute stock quote data

Tags: equities, market-data, algorithmic-trading, historical-data, ohlc

I know Yahoo has stock quote data (OHLCV). But it contains errors.

tdameritrade API have 1- and 5-minute data. But it only starts at 7AM ET, instead of 4AM ET. It is only limited to 182 trading days, which is rather limited.

Is there an alternative free quote data source that contains the 1- or 5-minute data from 4AM ET to 8PM ET for a duration much longer than 182 trading days?

The following question was asked 11 years ago. Many answers down there are outdated and irrelevant nowadays. They don't answer my specific questions, either.

[What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Instead of merging new answers and old/non-working answers to the same thread, it makes more sense to start a new thread for current working solutions. Thus, this question should not be closed.

Comment: The more specific your data-requirements become, the more likely you **won't** get it for free. When that is said, try [Polygon.io](https://polygon.io/) or maybe [alphavantage.co](https://www.alphavantage.co/). They both have pre-cleaned high-frequency data available, but I don't think it starts from 4 AM ET. I believe you have the ability to download more than 180 trading days on alphavantage.

Comment: @Pleb Please vote to open it as it is a different question.

Comment: @Pleb You voted to close it. The comment was "Original close reason(s) were not resolved". Please explain how this question is the same as the linked question. Why does my explanation that my question is not the same doesn't make sense to you? And how do you think the question can be changed? "Original close reason(s) were not resolved" provides no details and does not provide any positive feedback by any means.

Comment: Your question is not original. There are many questions regarding downloading free data under some special requirements. The above linked question is a good place to look for free data sources as a start (yes, it might need an update). As this is a small forum, we often don’t get that many new questions a day. Getting flooded with data questions is not the primary focus of this forum since it often lead to recommendations of the same sites. There might also be a general agreement that the specific data is only available through paid options (if you want good quality data).

Comment: There is also an [Open Data StackExchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), where your data-based question seems more suitable. You can try that SE and see if it yields better results :-)