# Historical end of day price data for non US stocks

Tags: equities, market-data, historical-data, price

I'm looking for historical end of day price data for non US-stocks. Preferably as bulk download for analysis, but an API would do also. Specific markets of interest:

- China
- Japan
- Major European markets: UK, France, Germany
- India
- Canada
- Korea
- Australia
- Any others would be great

I'm using Norgate data for US stocks and I'm looking for something comparable (split adjustment, survivorship bias free dataset) for other markets.

Does a single provider exist that has this data? Multiple providers?

Comment: Have you checked https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online ?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that post. www.eoddata.com/ is probably the closest thing I've come across so far