# Equities: API or Python Historical Fundamental Data Source

Tags: equities, market-data, historical-data, data-mining

All of my API sources have gone down/gone premium/don't provide sufficient data.

Does anyone know any sources (paid or free) where I can extract extensive income statements, balance sheets, etc. for large/small/value/growth stocks.

Cheers!

Comment: See this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: Check out [EquityRT](https://equityrt.com). It has good Excel APIs. Also described in the duplicate under equities.