# Looking for techniques or tools to add news/technical events to historical price charts

Tags: visualization, news

Before Google Finance changed its service, I remember I used to be able to see news or technical events on historical charts. It was beneficial  for me as I was able to see the impact of the news event on the price.

AFAIK, Google Finance does not provide the feature anymore.

Is there any alternative option that provides the same service and let me add news event to the price history charts?

**Update**

Please note that this is not a "Data Source" question. I've integrated my strategies and I am subscribed to variety data sources, some listed in this article:

[What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

I am looking to get a visualization like the following:

[image]

Note that above Google Finance feature has been discontinued.

> In above screenshot, note the integration between news headline events at the right and the labels on the chart time axis. I was able to map all news events on the time axis for many years back. RIP Google Finance.

Comment: No, this is a visualization question. I am trying to find the news catalyst for breakouts on historical chart. That way I can anticipate what similar category of incoming event can do the near term price.

Comment: Bloomberg for example. Not sure of any free services. I also wouldn't trust the accuracy of free services too much. Either way, I am not sure you will get much benefit from this. Have a look at the Focus box from Olivier Blanchard's textbook as shown [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/51777/37817). It covers all 4 possibilities (Good news - market up, Good news - market down, Bad news - Market up, Bad news - market down). It is all about investor expectations prior to the event.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the data source question. It has nothing to do with https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online