# Where to find historical data on corporate credit ratings

Tags: historical-data, credit-risk, credit-ratings, data-mining

I am looking for a parsed dataset with historical data for company credit ratings. I know NRSROs need to make their historical data public. I found  Moody's (https://ratings.moodys.com/sec-17g-7b), S&P and Fitches data, but I'm having a hard time turning it into a readable format like csv. I also found a nicely parsed dataset in Kaggle but it only has 2000 entries.

If anyone has a link to a dataset that might be useful I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)

Comment: No, this one is more broad, I checked the relevant sources, but I could only find sovereign credit ratings, which are not very relevant, since countries rarely default and the dtaset would be pretty unbalanced.

Answer (score 4):

I found this link with a lot of parsed data
http://ratingshistory.info/