# Does FINRA have an FTP dump of historical short interest?

Tags: historical-data, short-selling, short-interest

I am interested in downloading historical short interest data from Finra for analysis but I cannot find where they keep dump files. They have the data for OTC companies but not for all of the exchanges. The only option seems to be their API, which I would have to make a ton of calls to and is still limited to just the past 5 years. Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: @DimitriVulis FTP yes. sorry

Comment: I am looking for HISTORICAL data and that linked question doesn't address that.

Comment: Also check the sources at “[What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)”. Pls also note that data enquiries are not encouraged at this site as can be seen in “[the site’s guidance for questions](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)”.