# Daily quotes TIPS (treasury inflation protected securities) data

Tags: inflation, treasuries

I am looking for historical quotes for US TIPS (treasury inflation protection security). What is a reliable source of data to get this information?

Here's what I have tried:

1. I have looked into this question: [What data sources are
   available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online). But nothing useful on TIPS.
2. I have looked into several academic articles that use TIPS data.
   For example, this paper: [The TIPS-Treasury Bond Puzzle](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jofi.12032) uses
   TIPS data. They say they got their quotes from Bloomberg. I have
   access to Bloomberg but it is not clear to me how to identify all
   the TIPS that are outstanding, get their historical quotes, as well
   as data for past securities (that have reached maturity).  Related:
   Does anyone know any other academic articles that have used TIPS
   data?

In a nutshell, I am looking for a reliable database with daily quotes of US TIPS (including historical quotes).

Comment: Have you looked at https://fred.stlouisfed.org/?

Comment: I have. They quote the 10-year, 5-year and 30-year constant maturity but not the actually yields of underlying securities.

Comment: If you anyhow have access to Bloomberg, just ask F1 F1 (the help desk).

Comment: Type TII Govt Go.   You will see a list of all outstanding TIPS.  Type HP to get historical prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this exercise with BBG, so this is definitely possible. You can easily get a full list of CUSIPs (including matured ones) from [TreasuryDirect](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/auctions/auction-query/) and you can use the standard BDH function to get historical data (although probably not with Excel...)

There are a lot of alternatives depending on your budget. The highest quality data I've used came from TradeWeb and they can give you daily quotes for every TIPS going back in time. MorganMarkets has this as well (although I'm not sure whether you can get matured issues). Another great option is index providers. You can get TIPS index constituents and historical pricing from any of the index providers (BBG, FTSE, ICE, etc.). The downside is that they might not have TIPS with less than 1-year to maturity.

Comment: This is useful. The treasury direct link seems to show bills, bonds and notes. How can I identify TIPS from the set?

Comment: @phdstudent If you click on "Show/Hide Columns," one of the options is "TIPS." That column has a boolean indicator TIPS status.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you.