# Where can I find UK Gilt derived break even inflation rates?

Tags: fixed-income, inflation

The St Louis Fed publish data like this, https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T10YIE where the break even inflation rate is derived from treasuries and TIPS. Is there equivalent data derived from UK Gilts and inflation-linked gilts?

Comment: Have you reviewed the links on [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online) post?