# Benchmark Treasury Curve Data

Tags: bond, yield-curve

I want to calibrate US treasury bonds to get a benchmark curve as an exercise. I know that choice of bonds may be discretionary. But

1. can you point me to any good public data source where I can get UST data?
2. should I only choose bonds at par?
3. should I choose zero coupons (STRIPS) only or okay to have coupon-bearing bonds as well?

I am here not looking for full-fledged answer but just a right direction to jump-start myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online)