# Where to get Historical Options Data

Tags: options, option-pricing, finance

Where can I find the historical Options Data of Bank nifty? By historical I mean more than 1 year.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question lies here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online