Compustat Bankrupt Firms' Historical Data
I'm seeking financial statement data for firms that went bankrupt. I use the CRSP-Compustat-Merged (CCM) database from 1999-2022, but it lacks historical data for firms tagged with dlrsn 02 or 03 before these tags appear.
Where can I get that data?
Thanks!

Have you checked here? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online
