# Looking for most current Financial API that is fast and accurate for NYSE NASDAQ AMEX OTC and PINKs

Tags: equities, programming, algorithmic-trading

Looking to build a real time data feed, stock monitor window. 
Pretty much the same as equityfeed.com market viewer window, just with a few addedfeatures and or different filter columns with more up to date, current technologies. 
Any body know what API equity feed uses or an API be a better fit for more real time data than them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What broker/feed/APIsetup allows for recording the most accurate data (cheaply)?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-broker-feed-apisetup-allows-for-recording-the-most-accurate-data-cheaply)

Comment: Thank you. I read them but that was about 3 year so I was wondering if anything new had come up that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Any thoughts on Xignite?

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=xignite

Comment: I think there are some terms that we would benefit from if you could define. E.g.,  "current technologies" (something @Quinton Pike pointed out in [his answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/41735/33410). What does this mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

https://Polygon.io has the CTA + UTP + OTC feed.

I think this is what you're asking for. Using WebSockets and REST APIs for historic data. I believe this is what you mean by "current technologies".